# How do I make the nav bar always at the top?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using `Foundation` by `ZURB` and trying to get the nav bar to the top.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're using foundations, you can use:

```
<nav class="top-bar fixed"></nav>
```

Answer (score 30):

I have no idea what those 2 things are, but this is how you fix something in place regardless of window scroll position with CSS:

```css
#navbar {
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">NavBar!</div>

<p>lorem ispum dolor sit amet.</p><p>lorem ispum dolor sit amet.</p><p>lorem ispum dolor sit amet.</p><p>lorem ispum dolor <p>lorem ispum dolor sit amet.</p><p>lorem ispum dolor <p>lorem ispum dolor sit amet.</p>sit amet. sit amet<p>lorem ispum dolor sit amet.</p><p>lorem ispum dolor <p>lorem ispum dolor sit amet.</p><p>lorem ispum dolor <p>lorem ispum dolor sit amet.</p>sit amet. sit amet<p>lorem ispum dolor sit amet.</p><p>lorem ispum dolor <p>lorem ispum dolor sit amet.</p>sit amet.<p>lorem ispum dolor sit amet.</p><p>lorem ispum dolor <p>lorem ispum dolor sit amet.</p><p>lorem ispum dolor <p>lorem ispum dolor sit amet.</p>sit amet. sit amet<p>lorem ispum dolor sit amet.</p><p>lorem ispum dolor <p>lorem ispum dolor sit amet.</p>sit amet.
```

Comment: -1 there is an easier way for Foundation, look at @vinay's answer

Comment: My apologies. Why use 3 lines of CSS when you could use a whole framework! ;)

Comment: Why design a wheel every time you design a car? You should follow DRY methodologies even in your UI code base.

Comment: @EdCharbeneau, sure! There must be a framework that has function `foo(a, b) { return a + b; }` and we have to use it instead of writing our own! ;)

Comment: We should only need addition since through addition we can also subtract.

Answer (score 7):

Adding to Alex Wayne's answer:

I found it necessary to add a **z-index** with a high enough number for the navbar to appear always on top of other elements.

```
#navbar {
   z-index: 10000;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0px;
   width: 100%;
}​
```

Answer (score 3):

use the style:

```
position:fixed;
top:0px;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the class designed by bootstrap.

```
  <nav class="navbar-fixed-top">
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, import ActivatedRoute:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
```

Then in your constructor you can pull the parameter. For example:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        let myparam = params['myparam'];
        console.log(myparam); // Print the parameter to the console.  
    });
}
```

See https://www.mackenziesoftware.com/2020/06/how-to-get-param-from-url-in-angular.html for info.